# How to make auto reload on webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the `webpack.config.js` with:

```
entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js')
},
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true
}
```

I run from `cmd` the commnad `webpack-dev-server` , browse to `http://localhost:8080/` and when I make any change on the `app.js` I don't see any reload on my browser.

How could I do reload to my project with that webpack?

Answer (score 1):

First, the dev server write everything in memory, so you should use memory cache instead disk file.

```
// index.html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
// rather than <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Another, to fix your hot reload issue, set the content base to your source directory

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base src
```

hope is helpful to you!